# MVC2 scaffolding - can't see any data

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, scaffolding

I'm having a problem seeing any data in my MVC2 application.

I'm using your typical scaffolding setup, but when I view the index or details page I see no data at all.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here as I get no errors when compiling or running.

Here is my model(Users.cs):

```
public class Users
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Customer ID is required.")]
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
}
```

Here are the 2 controller(UsersController.cs) actions that matter:

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{

    static List<Users> users = new List<Users>();

    //
    // GET: /Users/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(users);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Users/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(Users u)
    {
        return View(u);
    }

}
```

And here are my views.

Users/Index.aspx

```
<table>
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.UserName }) %> |
            <%= Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", item )%> |
            <%= Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.UserName })%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.UserName) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.CustomerID) %>
        </td>
    </tr>

<% } %>

</table>

<p>
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
</p>
```

Users/Details.aspx

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Fields</legend>

    <div class="display-label">UserName</div>
    <div class="display-field"><%= Html.Encode(Model.UserName) %></div>

    <div class="display-label">CustomerID</div>
    <div class="display-field"><%= Html.Encode(Model.CustomerID) %></div>

</fieldset>
<p>
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  id=Model.UserName }) %> |
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</p>
```

All the pages load just fine with no errors, but no data is shown.  If I run the debugger the users list has 0 entries.

I am using SQL Server.  My connection string is in my web.config in the typical fashion:

My database has user data in it already.   It was generated with the default asp.net Web Site Administration Tool, which I am using for authentication.  This works perfectly.

So what am I doing wrong?  Any help is appreciated and if I need to give more info please let me know.

Comment: In your `UsersController`, the `List<Users>` is instantiated as a `new List<Users>()` which is fair enough, but is never populated (from the code given).  Did you omit that part?  If it wasn't omitted, then likely your pages aren't showing any data because your list of users contains exactly that; no data?  If that were the case, when you navigate to `../Users/` you should only be able to see a "Create New" link?

Comment: Smudge202 I guess thats my answer then, how do I populate it with the existing data using my model?  I do see the Create New link, but I wan't to read in existing data.  I don't actually plan to have the create button in production as the authentication already creates the users.

Comment: Will post an answer for you explaining...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UserController (as explained in comment on OP) instantiates your list of users with no data.

If you want to *seed* data, consider changing the declaration as follows:

```
public class UsersController : Controller 
{ 

    // static List<Users> users = GetSeededData(); - 
    // don't store a list locally, it isn't necessary if you have a database
    // consider holding the context instead perhaps?
    protected MyContext context = new MyContext();

    // 
    // GET: /Users/ 

    public ActionResult Index() 
    { 
        return View(context.users.ToList()); 
    } 

    // 
    // GET: /Users/Details/5 

    public ActionResult Details(int userId) 
    { 
        return View(context.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserId.Equals(userId)); 
    } 

}
```

A quick suggestion regarding your "persistance" (ignore this if you like, just a friendly tip)...

Consider introducting a *persistance layer*.  That is, if you want to persist data, consider storing it in a database, xml file, etc.  Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394709.aspx).  It's a great resource on MVC with lots of samples and tutorials, and half way down under the "Models" section it introduces you to the Entity Framework which can be used to store, retrieve, and update your data on a database quite nicely.

Comment: This sadly will not work.  I have a database full of user data already.  I need to read that data, so I can't instantiate any of it in the code.

Comment: Ok Duk, that's fine.  The bit you're missing in the code is fetching your data from the database.  How are you communicating with your database currently?  i.e. Entity Framework? Linq to SQL?  A different ORM?  ADO.Net?  I'll switch the above seed method to a quick L2S/EF4 example to get you started

Comment: I am using ADO.NET.  I realize my issue now.  For some reason I thought the model would know how to grab the data based of being named the same as the table and using the connection string.  I realize this is dumb of me, long day I guess.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not dumb, it can be hard to tell where the built-in scaffolding starts, and where it ends.  At least you know it doesn't quite cover this area for you (yet). ;-)